# How to pass multiple values in a single parameter for a stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I want to pass multiple values in a single parameter. SQL Server 2005

Comment: A single parameter can have a single value. Unless you make it a XML parameter and stick your multiple values into the XML and then parse it back into a list of parameters inside your stored procedure....

Comment: Why, oh why, would you ever want to do that?

Comment: Another way would be a comma-separated list of values... But not really any good way for SQL Server 2005. In SQL Server 2008, you could use table-valued parameters.

Comment: There's really nothing wrong with passing in xml.  I've personally written probably 50+ procs that take xml params.

Comment: We too use XML params, however they are expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* make a function:

```
ALTER  FUNCTION [dbo].[CSVStringsToTable_fn] ( @array VARCHAR(8000) )
RETURNS @Table TABLE ( value VARCHAR(100) )
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @separator_position INTEGER,
            @array_value VARCHAR(8000)  

        SET @array = @array + ','

        WHILE PATINDEX('%,%', @array) <> 0 
            BEGIN
                SELECT  @separator_position = PATINDEX('%,%', @array)
                SELECT  @array_value = LEFT(@array, @separator_position - 1)

                INSERT  @Table
                VALUES  ( @array_value )

                SELECT  @array = STUFF(@array, 1, @separator_position, '')
            END
        RETURN
    END
```

and select from it:

```
DECLARE @LocationList VARCHAR(1000)
SET @LocationList = '1,32'

SELECT  Locations 
FROM    table
WHERE   LocationID IN ( SELECT   CAST(value AS INT)
                           FROM     dbo.CSVStringsToTable_fn(@LocationList) )
```

OR

```
SELECT  Locations
FROM    table loc
        INNER JOIN dbo.CSVStringsToTable_fn(@LocationList) list
            ON CAST(list.value AS INT) = loc.LocationID
```

Which is extremely helpful when you attempt to send a multi-value list from SSRS to a PROC.

**Edited:** to show that you may need to CAST - However be careful to control what is sent in the CSV list

Comment: You're going to get implicit conversion above if your value column is varchar(100).  We have a fn_splitInt, fn_splitBigInt, etc.  Just like above, but you make value be an int or a bigint, and you cast it as int when inserting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your sproc take an **`xml`** typed input variable, then unpack the elements and grab them. For example:

```
DECLARE @XMLData xml

DECLARE 
    @Code varchar(10),
    @Description varchar(10)

SET @XMLData = 
'
    <SomeCollection>
      <SomeItem>
        <Code>ABCD1234</Code>
        <Description>Widget</Description>
      </SomeItem>
    </SomeCollection>
'

SELECT 
    @Code = SomeItems.SomeItem.value('Code[1]', 'varchar(10)'),
    @Description = SomeItems.SomeItem.value('Description[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM @XMLDATA.nodes('//SomeItem') SomeItems (SomeItem)

SELECT @Code AS Code, @Description AS Description
```

Result:

```
Code        Description
==========  ===========
ABCD1234    Widget
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to suggest. You can't really do so in SQL Server 2005. At least there is no a straightforward way. You have to use CSV or XML or Base 64 or JSON. However I strongly discourage you to do so since all of them are error prone and generate really big problems.

If you are capable to switch to SQL Server 2008 you can use Table valued parameters ([Reference1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx), [Reference2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx)).

If you cannot I'd suggest you to consider the necessity of doing it in stored procedure, i.e. do you really want (should/must) to perform the sql action using SP. If you are solving a problem just use Ad hoc query. If you want to do so in education purposes, <strike>you might try</strike> don't even try the above mentioned things.

Comment: Why aren't csv or xml straightforward?  They are much more straightforward than a table valued parameter where you have to define a custom table type for each type of parameter you want to pass.

Comment: @BrianWhite I think it's only straight forward to us because we've dealt with it for so long. If you think about it, having to pass values in a CSV (that you build at one point and unpack in another) is *really* dumb.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this, by:

1. **Passing CSV list** of strings as an argument to a (N)VARCHAR parameter, then parsing it inside your SP, [check here](http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2012/09/09/passing-multipledynamic-values-to-stored-procedures-functions-part1-by-passing-csv/).
2. Create a **XML string** first of all, then pass it as an XML datatype param. You will need to parse the XML inside the SP, you may need APPLY operator for this, [check here](http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2012/09/09/passing-multipledynamic-values-to-stored-procedures-functions-part2-by-passing-xml/).
3. Create a **temp table** outside the SP, insert the multiple values as multiple rows, no param needed here. Then inside the SP use the temp table, [check here](http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2012/09/09/passing-multipledynamic-values-to-stored-procedures-functions-part3-by-using-table/).
4. If you are in 2008 and above try **TVPs (Table Valued Parameters)** and pass them as params, [check here](http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2012/09/10/passing-multipledynamic-values-to-stored-procedures-functions-part4-by-using-tvp/).